# Batch file set variable from wmic

Tags: batch-file, wmic

Currently I am trying to get the speed value of the memory into a var like so

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%f in ('wmic memorychip get speed /value ^| find "="') do (set msp=%%f)
echo %msp%
```

But it never transfer the value into the variable.  If I do

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%f in ('wmic memorychip get speed /value ^| find "="') do (echo %%f)
```

it will echo out the correct value.  Why is this not storeing the value into variable?

Comment: Can't replicate. Your code runs fine for me.

Comment: Your code will currently only provide the speed of the last memory stick checked, _(with four banks that would likely be installed in BANK3)_. There is absolutely nothing preventing you from installing different speed RAM sticks in your system. To my knowledge the system will, in that case, work with the lowest of those speeds. I would therefore suggest, that you instead check the speed of each RAM stick, then determine and save only the lowest of those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon my recent comment, the following is intended to return the slowest memory stick speed in your system.

```batch-file
@Set "MSp=9999"&For /F EOL^=S %%G In (
    '""%__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe" MemoryChip Get Speed 2>NUL"')Do @(
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If 1%%G Lss 1!MSp! (EndLocal&Set /A MSp=%%G 2>NUL)Else EndLocal)
@Set MSp&Pause
```

The last line is included for demonstration purposes. I used `9999` as the initial value as it is unlikely that we'll have memory sticks with those speeds for several years, *(currently I think the fastest is `5000` and nobody can justify their cost!)*

Comment: This outputs "speed=2660"  , I need just the number 2660 stored in a var.

Comment: No it does not! The only returned output, other than that from `Pause`, will always begin with `MSp=`. I clearly stated within my answer that the last line was for demonstration purposes, if you have changed anything at all in the script I have posted, **_nothing should be added, removed or modified_**, then please do not expect it to work exactly the same! If for instance you changed all four instances of `MSp` to `speed` then that is the only way you will get the output you're reporting. If you don't want that output, then change `@Set MSp&Pause` to something else, e.g. `@Echo(%MSp%&Pause`.

Comment: I added and copied just as you have it.,   I did replay wrong. it says msp=2660 not speed

Comment: That is exactly what I asked it to return on my 'demonstration line'! So my script is working correctly and exactly as intended. I have already told you, in my last comment, if you dont want it to output the name of the variable followed by an `=` character, followed by the lowest speed, change the 'demonstration line' to read `@Echo(%MSp%&Pause` or `@Echo %%MSp%%=%MSp%&Pause` instead of `@Set MSp&Pause`. Please note that to use the value of a variable, named `MSp`, anywhere in your code, after line `4` of the above answer, you would use `%MSp%`.

Comment: sorry , I understand now.  There is a lot I don't know about batch files so I am trying to get threw this , just some things don't make sense till after I looked at it for some time.

Comment: So after all of my explanation and extra effort, you're still going to leave an answer which only outputs the speed of the last RAM stick, not the speed at which the system is effectively running them! BTW, just for information, the figures reported by WMI for this are not always accurate. PC's configured to run RAM at different settings from their defaults, _(most gaming systems)_, still report the RAM default settings instead of that which they're currently configured to run at.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In command line:

```
@for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %f in ('%__APPDIR__%\wbem\wmic.exe memorychip get speed /value ^|find/v " "')do @set "msp=%~f" && call echo/%msp%
```

In bat/cmd line:

```
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "_get_freq_mem=%__APPDIR__%\wbem\wmic.exe memorychip get speed /value"
for /f "tokens=2*delims== " %%f in ('"!_get_freq_mem!^|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe ."
')do set "_msp=%%f" && call set "_msp=!_msp: =!" && echo/!_msp!
%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe -1 && endlocal & goto :EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

You wish to access the value of msp outside the for loop after it has been changed in the for loop. In that case, you might probably need to expand the variables to their run-time values rather than the parse-time values. Try this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%f in ('wmic memorychip get speed /value ^| find "="') do (set msp=%%f)
echo !msp!
```

Comment: That did not help. still blank

Comment: plain wrong. You don't have to define the variable before. In fact `set msp=` actually *un*defines the variable. Delayed expansion *might* be the right solution, *if* Glen didn't show us his complete code and actually has the snippet within a codeblock.

Comment: @Stephan I see where I was wrong. Thank you for pointing that out! :)

Comment: @ParamSiddharth the edit did work and store the var as needed. ! thanks